# Let $m \in N$ and suppose that $p = 4m + 1$ is a prime number. Show that for any divisor $d$ of $m$ we have $(d/p) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck in this question: Let $m \in N$  and suppose that $p = 4m + 1$ is a prime number.

Show that for any divisor $d$ of $m$ we have $(d/p) = 1$ (this is Legendre symbol)

So far from Euler's theorem I know that: 
$d^{4m} = 1 \pmod p $ $\to$

$ (d^{2m})^2 = 1 \pmod p \to $  $ (d^{m})^2 = 1 \pmod p $ or $ (d^{m})^2 = (-1) \pmod p  $

Now by Euler Criteria I only need to prove that the only legal option is that  $ (d^{m})^2 = 1 \pmod p $ (in other words I need to prove that the other option can't happen) because if I prove it I'm done. but I'm stuck here..

thanks for your help   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove the result for $d=1$, $d=-1$, and $d$ prime. The result is obvious for $d=1$. And since $p=4m+1$, we have $(-1/p)=1$.

Now let $d=2$. If $2$ divides $m$, then $p$ is of the shape $8l+1$, so $(2/p)=1$.

Finally, let $d$ be an odd prime. By Quadratic Reciprocity we have $(d/p)=(p/d)=(1/d)=1$.

Comment: can you explain this please: (p/d)=(1/d)=1? and what if d is odd but not a prime?

Comment: In general, if $a\equiv b\pmod{q}$, then $(a/q)=(b/q)$. We have $(p/d)=((4m+1)/d)$. But since $d$ divides $m$, it follows that $4m+1\equiv 1\pmod{d}$. As to non-primes, recall that $(d_1d_2\cdots d_s/p)=(d_1/p)(d_2/p)\cdots (d_s/p)$, so if all prime divisors of the positive integer $d$ are quadratic residues, then $d$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: and as well if d is even but not a prime?

Comment: I explained in the answer why $(2/p)=1$. It is a standard fact that $2$ is a QR of the odd prime $p$ iff $p$ is of the shape $8k\pm 1$.